# Create some tool for converting data from one database to another

Tags: relational-database, data-migration, database-migration

This is kind of implementation question maybe. I wonder if I where to make a tool to convert some relational database to some other kind of database. What would the approach be?

If I for example want to convert data and the structure from a mysql database to mssql. Would I need to use regular expression to parse the SQL-file? Or maybe I could convert it to XML or JSON first and from that structure parse into my targeted database?

Using existing tools for converting mysql to mssql or anything similar is not in this scope. Since I want to know how it is actually done.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's kind of a broad question, but generally speaking, having your own abstract representation of the structure and data would be a good thing, because you could extend your system "easily" by writing importers and exporters, and actually decouple your code a little by abstracting the relational db concepts into your own format.

The importers would "reverse engineer" a given database, by converting it to your own representation (as you say, xml/json or even your own query language -that would be better I guess-). Then the exporters would just convert from your format to the requested SQL dialect. No regular expressions, no other stuff "hardcoded".

This will allow you to extend your system and support a bigger number of sources and targets, and also handle errors like some SQL features from a "source" not supported in the selected "target".

My 2 cents, hope it helps!